# How to select a <div> on a particular tab clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am designing a tabs of my own for tab navigation I used google api and jquery.

Here my fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/fk7y2d5L/2/

but in fiddle i didnt add google api link.

Here is my js code

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{

$("header ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("header ul li a").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");  
    });

    $(this).addClass("active");

            var tabtitle=$(this).attr("title");
    $.show('#tab'+tabtitle);
});
});
```

Here I am trying is on click of each tag i am trying to display respective `div` tag. But I cant able to do it. can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You don't need google api for this. Just include jquery library in your html page as shown below. Put your code inside `$(function(){..});` which will ensure that script applies after loading whole DOM structure.

For more information on jQuery visit - **[JQuery.com](http://jquery.com/)**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



$(function()
{
    // Just for demonstration purposes, change the contents/active state using jQuery
    $("header ul li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove active class from all tabs
        $("header ul li a").removeClass("active");  
        // hide all tab div
        $('div[id^="tab"]').hide();

        //add active class to clicked tab
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // show clicked tab content div
        var tabtitle=$(this).attr("title");
        $('#tab'+tabtitle).show();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/fk7y2d5L/3/)**

Comment: what happens in line`$('div[id^="tab"]').hide();`

Comment: ur addClass has to be first

Comment: because you don't have respective `Blog` div hence not showing. `$('div[id^="tab"]').hide();` this is to hide all div whose id start with tab ( see start with selector in jquery)

Comment: `addClass` should be after `$("header ul li a").removeClass("active");` as this will remove class from all a tag, if you put `addClass` before it then no use

Answer (score 0):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fk7y2d5L/11/

```
$(function () {
    // Just for demonstration purposes, change the contents/active state using jQuery
    $("header ul li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Remove the active class from any anchors that have it
        $("header ul li a.active").removeClass("active");

        // Add active to the selected anchor
        $(this).addClass("active");

        var tabtitle = $(this).attr("title");

        // Hide all divs that start with id=tab
        $('#main div[id^=tab]').hide();

        // Show the selected div
        $('#tab' + tabtitle).show();
    });

    // initial hide of all tabs
    $('#main div[id^=tab]').hide();

    // Trigger initial selection
    $('header a.active').trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: Thank you , but here initially it shows all `div` how to overcome it

Comment: `$('#main div[id^=tab]').hide();` at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fk7y2d5L/8/

Comment: Note: There is often no need for an `each` for most jQuery methods (e.g. `removeClass`), as they apply to a selection of elements.

Comment: I am very new to Jquery, here one small problem is, when I click on blog its content is not visible and when page loaded, blog is clicked so its content should be visible when it loaded. How to so this?

Comment: You have no `tabblog` div. That's all. It says "this is a blog", but is called `tababout`

Comment: Have added correct divs and auto-clicked the initially `active` anchor  using `trigger` (so you see the default "blog" div).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to hide the tabs, lets say that you do so by adding a class `tab` for all corresponding `<div>`'s along with the following css

```
.tab {
  display:none;
}
```

Then set the initially active tab as visible by applying the class `visible` given below to it.

```
div.tab.visible {
  display:block;
}
```

Now you can use the following JS to make it work:

```
$("header ul li a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".active").removeClass("active"); // you don't need to iterate over using each
  $(this).addClass("active");

  var tabtitle = $(this).attr("title");
  $("#main div.tab.visible").removeClass("visible"); // hide actve tab
  $('#tab' + tabtitle).addClass("visible"); // show selected tab
});
```

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/fk7y2d5L/10/)

*Side note: I added the missing tab `blog` and added the corresponding text for the demo*

Comment: Thank u, but here for about and register tab it shows same content

Comment: for me blog is not visible and for next tabs it shows previous contents.

Comment: @Raghu did you mean it's not working in my demo or for you locally..? :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. No need for anything other than just jQuery.

Secondly: Personally, I would default all the tabs to being hidden, and only showing them when the "active" class is on them.

Also, you might want to add some actual class names to the tabs and the tab-content so you have better control. ".tab" for the tabs, and ".tab-content" for the content.

The javascript code is then fairly simple and understandable:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".tab").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".tab.active, .tab-content.active").removeClass("active");    

        $(this).addClass("active");
        var tabtitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $('#tab'+tabtitle).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle with new class names](http://jsfiddle.net/fk7y2d5L/12/)